# Android sms getting the response error/notification if the message has been delivered or sent successfully

Tags: android, sms

```
How can i get the error when sending message and the response when the message has been successfully sent?
```

Here is my code:

```
try {    
   String message = "Hello World! Now we are going to demonstrate " + 
      "how to send a \n message with more than \n 160 characters from your Android application.";
   SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
   ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(message ); 
   smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, null, null);
} catch (Exception e) {
   //HOW CAN I GET THE SMS RESPONES HERE
   Toast.makeText(context, "SMS faild!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot `catch` a sent or delivery success/failure, as it is not an `Exception`, nor any other type of `Throwable`.

You will need to create `PendingIntent`s for *sent* and *delivered* actions, and pass them in the method used to send the SMS. The following is an example that can be used for single or multipart messages.

```
public static final String ACTION_SMS_SENT = "com.mycompany.myapp.SMS_SENT";
public static final String ACTION_SMS_DELIVERED = "com.mycompany.myapp.SMS_DELIVERED";

private void sendSMS(String number, String message) {
    final SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();        
    final ArrayList<String> parts = sm.divideMessage(message);
    final int ct = parts.size();

    final ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentPis = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>(ct);      
    final ArrayList<PendingIntent> delPis = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>(ct);       

    for (int i = 0; i < ct; i++) {
        final PendingIntent piSent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                                       i,
                                       new Intent(ACTION_SMS_SENT),
                                       0);
        final PendingIntent piDel =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                                       i,
                                       new Intent(ACTION_SMS_DELIVERED),
                                       0);

        sentPis.add(piSent);
        delPis.add(piDel);
    }

    sm.sendMultipartTextMessage(number, null, parts, sentPis, delPis);
}
```

You will need to register a `BroadcastReceiver` to get the results. A basic Receiver example:

```
public class SmsResultReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(ACTION_SMS_SENT)) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case -1: //Activity.RESULT_OK
                    break;

                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    break;

                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    break;

                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    break;

                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    break;

                default:
            }
        }
        else if (action.equals(ACTION_SMS_DELIVERED)) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case -1: //Activity.RESULT_OK
                    break;

                case 0: //Activity.RESULT_CANCELED
                    break;

                default:
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do note that each Receiver will be run once for each message part. I would also mention that not all carriers provide delivery reports, so there's no guarantee that the *delivered* `PendingIntent`s will ever fire.

An instance of this Receiver can be registered dynamically with the `Context#registerReceiver()` method, or the Receiver class can be registered in the manifest with a `<receiver>` element, and the appropriate `<intent-filter>`s.

Comment: should I need to change mycompany or my app name in "com.mycompany.myapp.SMS_SENT"

Comment: @user1448783 Simple answer to first question: Yes, you probably should. The action Strings should be unique, so your Receiver isn't fired by someone else's app, and vice versa. Most people include the package name, of which `com.mycompany.myapp` is an example, to help ensure uniqueness.

Comment: @user1448783 As for the second question, there are many, many examples already on this site of statically registering a Receiver in the manifest.