# Android Send SMS programmatically

Tags: android, sms

I am trying to send a sms programmatically but in some cases it is not working.

If I calling like this - `sendSMS("+918444380502", "BAL");` sms send successful no problem but if I am trying to send like this - `sendSMS("+918444380502", "El teléfono no está registrado o ligado a un usuario, favor de registrarlo");` it's not sending any clue !!

Send sms code is follows -

```
//---sends an SMS message to another device---
public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    //---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    //---when the SMS has been delivered---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
            stopSelf();
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
}
```

Comment: Do you get any exception? Have you studied the docs about string encoding to get multiword encoding through it? Because you use special chars in your second sms.

Comment: for unicode sms, 70 characters in one message at max, or use sendMultipartTextMessage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code worked for me like this thanks to **Mike M** -

```
private void sendSMS(String number, String msg)
{
    SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
    ArrayList<String> parts = sm.divideMessage(msg);

    Intent iSent = new Intent(ACTION_SMS_SENT);
    PendingIntent piSent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, iSent, 0);
    Intent iDel = new Intent(ACTION_SMS_DELIVERED);
    PendingIntent piDel = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, iDel, 0);

    if (parts.size() == 1)
    {
        msg = parts.get(0);
        sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, msg, piSent, piDel);
    }
    else
    {
        ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentPis = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
        ArrayList<PendingIntent> delPis = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

        int ct = parts.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < ct; i++)
        {
            sentPis.add(i, piSent);
            delPis.add(i, piDel);
        }

        sm.sendMultipartTextMessage(number, null, parts, sentPis, delPis);
        stopSelf();
    }
}

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(ACTION_SMS_SENT))
        {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (action.equals(ACTION_SMS_DELIVERED))
        {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention (and I should make a note on that post), that method is very generic, and will simply broadcast the sent/delivered actions for each successful message part. If you wish to bundle any info with the broadcasts - such as current part number, total parts, etc. - to be handled in the Receiver, you may have to change the `requestCode` and/or `flags` arguments in the `getBroadcast()` calls, depending on your requirements.

Comment: Any way It's  fulfill my requirements I have upvoted you

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't send Texts with unicode characters, try using `sendMultipartTextMessage` instead.

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
ArrayList<String> textMsgs = sms.divideMessage(message);
sms.sendMultipartTextMessage (phoneNumber, null, textMsgs, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

Comment: This is correct, except it's expecting ArrayLists of the PendingIntents and message parts. [Here's an example.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890415/android-sms-getting-the-response-error-notification-if-the-message-has-been-deli/22902900#22902900)

Comment: same error. If I am putting last 2 parameter null, null then there is no error. But I need that too...

Comment: You can't be getting the same error since this time you are passing an ArrayList just like it wanted you to. Does the error still say the same thing?

Comment: @bumba You need ArrayLists of the PendingIntents, too, with the same number as the number of message parts. Check the link in my last comment for an example.